# Extract all negative number from column2 in another file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a very long data file "file.dat" with two columns.
Here I am putting a very small portion. I want to extract all the negative numbers from the column2 into another file let us say file2.dat and similarly for positive numbers from the same column2 to another file file3.dat

```
    4.0499   -7.1787
    4.0716   -7.1778
    4.0932   -7.1778
    4.1148   -7.1785
    4.1365   -7.1799
    4.1581   -7.1819
    4.1798   -7.1843
    4.2014   -7.1868
    4.2231   -7.1890
    4.2447   -7.1902
    4.2663   -7.1900
    4.2880   -7.1886
                        <-------Note: this kind of break is also there in many places 
    0.0000    2.1372
    0.0707    2.1552
    0.1414    2.2074
    0.2121    2.2864
    0.2828    2.3791
    0.3535    2.4646
    0.4242    2.5189
    0.4949    2.5207
    0.5655    2.5098
```

**Expected Results for Negative numbers file2.dat**

```
 -7.1787
 -7.1778
 -7.1778
 -7.1785
 -7.1799
 -7.1819
 -7.1843
 -7.1868
 -7.1890
 -7.1902
 -7.1900
 -7.1886
```

**Expected Results for Positive numbers file3.dat**

```
2.1372
2.1552
2.2074
2.2864
2.3791
2.4646
2.5189
2.5207
2.5098
```

**Nearest Solution I found**

This solution did not work for me because of my lack of knowledge.

http://www.unixcl.com/2009/11/awk-extract-negative-numbers-from-file.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite simple to do with `awk`. You simply check the value in the 2nd column and write it out based on its value, e.g.

```
awk '$2<0 {print $2 > "negative.dat"} $2>=0 {print $2 > "positive.dat"}' file
```

Where the two rules used by `awk` above are:

- `$2<0 {print $2 > "negative.dat"}`, if the value in the 2nd column is less than 0, write to `negative.dat`,
- `$2>=0 {print $2 > "positive.dat"}`, if the value in the 2nd column is greater than or equal to 0, write to `"positive.dat"`.

**Example Use/Output**

With you example data in `file` (without your comment), running the above would result in:

```
$ cat negative.dat
-7.1787
-7.1778
-7.1778
-7.1785
-7.1799
-7.1819
-7.1843
-7.1868
-7.1890
-7.1902
-7.1900
-7.1886
```

The positive values in:

```
$ cat positive.dat
2.1372
2.1552
2.2074
2.2864
2.3791
2.4646
2.5189
2.5207
2.5098
```

Comment: Wow :). Thanks a lot it was really very quick.
I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You are quite welcome, good luck with your scripting! Awk is the swiss-army-knife of text processing, well worth learning [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents)

Comment: Thanks again :)
I will try my best to learn it :)

Answer (score 3):

David's answer is pretty good, here is a shorter `awk` one liner using ternary condition:

```sh
awk 'NF>1 {print $2 > ($2 < 0 ? "neg.dat" : "pos.dat")}' file
```

Comment: Thank you, @anubhava, I appreciate your help :)

Comment: @sai, Good that these codes(David sir's and anubhava sir's codes) worked for you, you could up-vote all helpful answers too for encouraging them on Stack overflow cheers and happy learning.